# Writing to csv after parsing with Beautifulsoup results in separated values or an empty output file

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

```
<table class="table_grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>First Name1</td>
                    <td>email1@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Processor</td>

                    <td></td>   

                                <td><a href="/Account/EditUser?id=4c4e6455-7d27-4abf-93c9-5584f09674d5">Edit</a></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>First Name2</td>
                    <td>email2@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Officer</td>

                    <td></td>   

                                <td><a href="/Account/EditUser?id=267e90eb-6fa4-4286-88d9-738913cdd7ea">Edit</a></td>

                </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to parse the text from this table and write it to a csv file. It writes to csv but every letter ends up in a new column. |F|i|r|s|t| when I am looking for |First|.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table_grid'})

with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for body in table.findAll('tr'):
        rows = body.getText()
        writer.writerow(rows)
```

This is my code. Looking at similar issues on here I tried fixing this issue with the following:

```
writer.writerow([rows])
```

However this resulted in a blank csv file. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to write *every cell into it's own column*:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in table('tr'):
        writer.writerow([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row(['td', 'th'])])
```

Note that I'm using some shortcuts here - `table('tr')` is an alternative concise way to do `table.find_all('tr')`.

Also, an alternative way to dump the HTML table into CSV would be to use `pandas` library, in particular - [`.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and [`.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) methods.

Comment: That definitely writes every cell into it's own column, thank you. However, its now missing the headers where it was pulling them before. Would I add:     for row in table('th'): as well?

Comment: @nvachhan well, one idea is to find both `td` and `th` elements for every row - please see the updated answer.

Comment: New answer works and makes sense thanks. Last question, what is the purpose of: (strip=True) ? I will try out pandas next time.

Comment: @nvachhan `strip=True` helps to remove the extra whitespaces and newlines around the texts. Thanks.